# SFML opening image files in xcode?

Tags: c++, sfml

Im attempting to load a .gif file into a texture in SFML in xCode and I cannot figure out how open it.

```
    float radius = 2.50e+11;
    CelestialBody sun(0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 1.9890e+30, "sun.gif", radius);
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode((radius/600000000.0)*2,(radius/600000000.0)*2), "test");
    while (window.isOpen())
    {

        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {

            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        sun.draw(window,sf::RenderStates::Default);
        window.display();
    }


    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code it builds just fine and a window gets displayed however there is no image in it, when I look at the console I have an error that says "Failed to load image "sun.gif". Reason: Unable to open file"

The file is located in the same folder that my .cpp and .hpp files are, I assumed that it would look for the image there but now i am unsure where to put the image in order for xcode to be able to find it.

Comment: How are you running the program?  Note that a filename like `sun.gif` is relative to your working directory when running the executable.

Comment: im just clicking run in xCode, and yes I thought of writing out the whole path to the file however for this homework assignment the file names are take from a txt file so all that will be input is sun.gif, what is it you mean by working directory? i have the file in the folder that has my cpp file and my xcode project etc.

Comment: The [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) is the directory that an application starts in (which is not necessarily the location of the executable or the source code).  Any relative paths in the code are relative to the working directory.  Xcode should provide a setting that lets you change what working directory is used when launching things from within Xcode.

Comment: Please provide some code for your `CelestialBody`. How are you trying to load the file? Please try producing a [example]